# How can I select the difference between the highest and second highest field value using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, max, min, window-functions

I have a table as follows:

```
id, party, constituency, votes
```

there are records for each of the UK voting constituencies, a data example is:

```
1, Conservative, Carlisle, 21780
2, Labour, Carlisle, 18932
3, Green, Carlisle, 2310
4, Conservative, Kensington, 22098
5, Labour, Kensington, 22056
6, Green, Kensington, 3209
7, Conservative, Islington, 32908
8, Labour, Islington, 33005
9, Green, Islington, 5409
```

I want to identify the seats where the lowest (and greatest) majorities exist. I would like to select all fields where the difference between the max vote and second placed vote, for a given constituency, is less than 50 for example. So I have tried:

```
SELECT *, 
       max.votes as max, 
       second_max.votes as max2 
FROM   election
WHERE  (max - max2) < 50  
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

Needless to say this does not work. Please can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For databases where `ROW_NUMBER` doesn't exist, but `EXISTS` does?

An `EXISTS` can be used to get the top N within a partition.

And then you can aggregate those top 2 groups.

```
SELECT constituency
, MAX(votes) AS votes1
, MIN(votes) AS votes2
, MAX(votes)-MIN(votes) AS votes_diff
FROM election e
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM election e2
   WHERE e2.constituency = e.constituency
     AND e2.votes > e.votes
   HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
)
GROUP BY constituency
HAVING (MAX(votes) - MIN(votes)) < 50
ORDER BY votes_diff DESC;
```

**Using this sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE election (
 party varchar(30) not null, 
 constituency varchar(30) not null, 
 votes numeric(10) not null
);
INSERT INTO election (party, constituency, votes) VALUES
('Conservative', 'Carlisle', 21780),
('Labour', 'Carlisle', 18932),
('Green', 'Carlisle', 2310),
('Conservative', 'Kensington', 22098),
('Labour', 'Kensington', 22056),
('Green', 'Kensington', 3209),
('Conservative', 'Islington', 32908),
('Labour', 'Islington', 33005),
('Green', 'Islington', 5409);
```

**Returns:**

```
constituency    votes1  votes2  votes_diff
Kensington      22098   22056   42
```

Comment: thank you. It works fine for regular database. I now need to figure out how to translate it into an elasticsearch query!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from (
    select
        e.*,
        row_number() over(partition by constituency order by votes desc) rn
    from election e
) t
where 
    rn in (1, 2)
    and max(votes) over(partition by constituency) 
        - min(votes) over(partition by constituency) < 50
```

This query gives you the 2 records with the highest `votes` for each `constituency`, if and only if the difference between them is less than 50.

NB: this works as long as your RDMBS supports window functions (MySQL < 8.0 is a notable exception).

Comment: thank you for this. The additional problematic aspect, which i did not mention, is that  I will use the elasticsearch sql translate api to tune this into an elasticsearch query! I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions, but I would  use conditional aggregation:

```
select constituency,
       max(votes) as max_votes, min(votes) as second_place
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by constituency order by votes desc) as seqnum
      from election e
     ) e
where seqnum in (1, 2)
group by consistuency
having min(votes) > max(votes) - 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query solves the problem using conditional aggregation instead of windowed functions. I've used parts of GMB's query to come up with this solution:

```sql
select constituency, max(votes) as maxvotes, min(votes) as minvotes from (
    select
        e.*,
        row_number() over(partition by constituency order by votes desc) rnk
    from election e ) as x
where 
    rnk in (1, 2)
group by constituency
having min(votes) > max(votes) - 50
```